# Configure Apache to proxy calls for a WebService behind a VPN

Tags: apache-2.2, vpn, proxy, web-services

I have an uncommon situation.
I need to access from an embedded platform a WebService that needs VPN authentication.
I can't connect to the VPN from the embedded platform because it only supports windows clients.

I believe the only solution for that is to use a Windows PC to connect to the VPN and act as a proxy to the embedded platform.

The VPN login is done through a Check Point web client (works only on Internet Explorer).
The server I need to access is exposed through the VPN as:

```
http://10.2.77.66/service.svc
```

I've already managed to make the VPN work. I can access the following address from from the PC web browser:

```
http://10.2.77.66/service.svc?wsdl
```

However I really have no idea on how to configure a proxy server so the embedded platform can access the WebService.

Can anyone give me some hints on that?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered how to do it.

Just create a tunnel. The client may access the local machine at a given port (8081 for instance). The tunnel will forward this port to the VPN obtained IP address.

If anyone needs more information, just ask.

Comment: I need, please!